# Mac OS X Hide cursor (Applescript or App?)

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm working with a digital signage application and uses a Mac Mini as a media player. The application is just a full screen kiosk mode in Chrome.

Can I somehow hide the cursor when idle for 5 seconds? Are there any apps or applescripts for this? CSS don't work unless you move the cursor when the computer starts up.

Answer (score 3):

Cursorcerer, its free and can hide your mouse when idle or on a certain key

Comment: Thank's! I've actually tried this but as soon as I restart the mac mini, I have to manually open Cursorcerer again to make it work again :/

Comment: [Cursorcerer](http://doomlaser.com/cursorcerer) still works in High Sierra (macOS 10.13)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try CSS again and use MouseTools http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html

Use it in a script run at startup to move the mouse some, delay it if need be to overcome the cursor needing to move issue.